# C# WCF + HTTP POST

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Добрый день!

У меня есть WCF-сервис, опубликованный на сервере в IIS.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать, способен ли мой сервис принимать HTTP POST запросы? С этим сервисом я работал только через прокси-класс.

Спасибо.

web.config моего сервиса:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DSN" connectionString="Data Source=SBDP-CENTER-X06.bank.lan; Initial Catalog=CardServices; Integrated Security=true;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://sbdp-x06.bank.lan:4413/PinSetup.svc/SoapBufferedCert"
        behaviorConfiguration="clientEndpointCredential" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup" contract="PinSetupService.IPinSetup"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup" />
      <endpoint address="https://test.lan:4400/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate" contract="SmsGateServiceReference.ISmsGate"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate" />
      <endpoint address="https://sbdp-center.lan:4004/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1"
        contract="SrNotifyService.FZCoreModuleContract_2_1" name="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CertCoreBehavior" name="PrepaidServiceNS.PrepaidService">
        <endpoint address="SoapBufferedCert" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityBinding" contract="PrepaidServiceNS.IPrepaid"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <!--  Сертификаты  -->
        <behavior name="CertCoreBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling
              maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
              maxConcurrentCalls="1000"
              maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" includeWindowsGroups="false"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />              
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientEndpointCredential">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="j-TestCertClient" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecurityBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис работающий под IIS принимает POST/GET запросы. Тут вопрос в каком формате?! SOAP или REST?

Определяется это настройкой WCF в конфиге или в коде - *Binding для endpoint.

Comment: Спасибо. Формат -  REST.

Comment: "Binding" для endpoint настраиваются в моем конфиге? Т.к. это КО МНЕ подключатся, то endpoint должен настраиваться в их конфиге. поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Да, в конфиге сервиса. И клиент должен быть настроен на одну из endpoint.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуй - я опубликовал свой веб-конфиг сервиса, в какой секции настраивается доступ к моему сервису по HTTP  POS ? (в моем конфиге указано, что мой сервис использует 3 других, но к этой задаче это не относится)